# Winff exits with "Unrecognized option" error

Tags: ffmpeg, convert, winff

I installed ffmpeg completely from [this Guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide). I installed Winff in Ubuntu but when I want to try convert I face to this error:

```
ffmpeg version git-2013-11-15-995f450 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 15 2013 18:32:56 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu8)
  configuration: --disable-yasm
  libavutil      52. 53.100 / 52. 53.100
  libavcodec     55. 43.100 / 55. 43.100
  libavformat    55. 21.100 / 55. 21.100
  libavdevice    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
  libavfilter     3. 91.100 /  3. 91.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
Unrecognized option 'preset'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
Press Enter to Continue
```

...I installed libavcodec-extra-53 also..what's soution?

Comment: How you call Winff?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't follow the guide properly because your ffmpeg configure only contains `--disable-yasm`. The presets are probably for encoding with libx264, but since your ffmpeg configure is lacking `--enable-gpl --enable-libx264` you do not have support for this encoder.

The `libavcodec-extra-53` package will not affect your compiled ffmpeg, so it does nothing in this case.

Comment: so how I enable Yasm in ffmpeg?

Comment: @Deniz See [How to Compile FFmpeg on Ubuntu](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide).

Comment: Its that linked I followed how to compile ffmpeg..I didnot have problem in Ubuntu 12.04 but in new, Ubutu 13.10 I have problem..

Comment: @Deniz The guide installs yasm and does not use `--disable-yasm`. What is the problem, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. The answer is simple.
Look at the version number of your libavcodec. It's 55.
However the most recent presets on the WinFF website are for version 54.

Until winf posts new presets your only choice is to use a different ffmpeg or play with the presets till you find a combination that works. I tried but the output is horrible.