# How to Remove ffmpeg completely in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: installation, uninstall, ffmpeg

I tried this [guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide) 
to install ffmpeg, but now I want to remove it completely from Ubuntu 13.10, but when I did that guide to remove, ffmpeg is still there!
How to remove it exactly?

after removing ffmpeg I see this output again:

```
deniz@deniz-Ubuntu:~/Downloads$ ffmpeg
ffmpeg version git-2013-11-15-995f450 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 15 2013 18:32:56 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu8)
  configuration: --disable-yasm
  libavutil      52. 53.100 / 52. 53.100
  libavcodec     55. 43.100 / 55. 43.100
  libavformat    55. 21.100 / 55. 21.100
  libavdevice    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
  libavfilter     3. 91.100 /  3. 91.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options]     outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'
```

Comment: Are you sure the ffmpeg version you are using is from the guide or from the repository? Show the complete console output of the `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: yeah I compiled it from that guide, in compiling only problem was "yasm" and I compile "ffmpeg --disable yasm" option, just that!..

Comment: can I‌ ask how I can enable yasm in ffmpeg?

Comment: The guide shows exactly how to compile or install yasm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute this command:

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep ffmpeg
```

If this command returns any output then it means that you've installed it and doesn't removed completely. Now you can remove all ffmpeg using following command:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove $(dpkg -l | grep ffmpeg | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' ' ')
sudo apt-get --purge remove $(dpkg -l | grep ffmpeg | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' ' ')
```

**Edit**

`man ffmpeg` opening manual doesn't mean that it was there. It was because some of the configuration files remained in system when you un-install the program. You can delete them but it is not recommended. I'm posting the command to search all the files in your system matching with `ffmpeg` and delete them all. But remember it is not recommended to do so..

```
sudo find / | grep -w ffmpeg | sudo xargs rm -r -f
```

It should remove all the `ffmpeg` files and also you'll not be able to open the `manual` again.

Comment: I tried these commands but when I get output of "man ffmpeg"...ffmpeg is still there! :(

Comment: Does this command return any output: `sudo dpkg -l | grep ffmpeg`? Reply..

Comment: not output now..but "man ffmpeg" is still there..

Comment: @Deniz the ffmpeg man pages are in another packages.

Comment: @Deniz: Check my edit..

Comment: please kumar check my edit too..I dont see output when I removed by your guide but...

Comment: @Deniz: don't worry about that, it is not installed :) You can also use these command to know the status: `sudo dpkg -L ffmpeg` and `sudo whereis ffmpeg`. If these commands return any output delete these files/folder after giving appropriate path.

Answer (score 6):

[How to Compile FFmpeg in Ubuntu](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide) tells you how to undo everything in the [Reverting Changes Made by This Guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide#RevertingChangesMadebyThisGuide) section:

```
rm -rf ~/ffmpeg_build ~/ffmpeg_sources ~/bin/{ffmpeg,ffprobe,ffserver,vsyasm,x264,yasm,ytasm}

sudo apt-get autoremove autoconf automake build-essential git libass-dev \
libgpac-dev libmp3lame-dev libopus-dev libsdl1.2-dev libtheora-dev \
libtool libva-dev libvdpau-dev libvorbis-dev libvpx-dev libx11-dev \
libxext-dev libxfixes-dev texi2html zlib1g-dev

hash -r
```

However, seeing your other recent [ffmpeg question](https://askubuntu.com/q/377426/59378) it appears that you did not follow the guide or did not follow it correctly so this may not work for you.

The guide does not install ffmpeg to the system. This is to avoid conflicts with packages from the repository, but I'm guessing you did install to the system with `sudo make install` without using `checkinstall`; therefore it is not integrated in the package management system. If this is the case then try:

```
cd ~/ffmpeg
sudo make uninstall
hash -r
```

The guide is supposed to make compiling easy since the ideas is that the user must only successfully copy and paste, but compiling is not for everyone and results may vary.